# How to install old version Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions on Ubuntu 16.4.4

Tags: function, firebase, ubuntu

I was using version <= 0.9.1 of firebase sdk. Now, after operation system reinstallation i had to install firebase sdk again. But i was able only to install the current version, using npm. There were major changes in firebase SDK after version 0.9.1, newer version isn't backward compatible so all my functions won't work if I deploy them. I just want to change 1 little thing in a function, I don't want to migrate to new version. How to install old version of firebase sdk? I'm using ubuntu 16.4.4.

Comment: It can be usefull to use -g flag aswell as sudo

Comment: The old version isn't supported.  You really should take the time to upgrade, as you will be missing out on new features and bug fixes until you do.

Comment: it's impossible to make it done, npm force me to install firebase-admin@~5.10.0. When I have installed it, npm still complain about firebase-admin and don't let me install firebase-functions@0.9.1. Even flag -f don't help